# How to access window object within _app.tsx in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, auth0

I am using NextJS/React framework for my application, and currently implementing Auth0.
Since I need to handle the multiple path (localhost & actual address), I want to access `window` object like so.

_app.tsx

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN ?? ''}
      clientId={process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID ?? ''}
      redirectUri={getAuth0RedirectURL()}
    >
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Auth0Provider>
  )
}
```

In my `getAuth0RedirectURL` function, I simply trying to access window object and handle if the current environment is dev or production.

```
export const getAuth0RedirectURL = (): string => {
  const url = new URL(window.location.origin) // here, I got error because window is not defined
  url.pathname = process.env.AUTH0_PATH

  return url.toString()
}
```

I do think the current code does not work ( `window is undefined` ) because it doesn't handle client-side so no `window` object yet appears.

I am not sure how I can correctly access the `window` object in `_app.tsx` so I can securely access `window.location.origin` path?

Answer (score 0):

You are right in saying that the code does not work because `window` is a browser object while you are trying to access `window` on the server, hence you are getting `undefined`.

1. What you can do is use an `if statement` to check if `window` is `undefined` or not.

```js
if (typeof window === "undefined") return null;
return (
  <Auth0Provider
    domain={process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN ?? ''}
    clientId={process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID ?? ''}
    redirectUri={getAuth0RedirectURL()}
  >
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </Auth0Provider>
)
```

2. Another way to achieve this would be to use [dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) which is provided by NextJS.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('../components/List'), {
  ssr: false
})

export default () => <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
```

3. Alternatively, and this is my recommendation as well, you can find the [recommended solution](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js) by the Auth0 team which is to *not* use their SPA SDK but instead do authentication server-side. Which is the NextJS way of doing things to.

Answer (score 0):

@Ansh's answer is right.

But why not using node env directly?

```
redirectUri={process.env.AUTH0_PATH}
```

If you need to check current environment:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

In case, you still want to access window, you can use:

```
global?.window && window.location.origin
```